# Border/Titlebar not properly displaying in SDL OSX

Tags: c, macos, sdl

I was just following lazyfoo's SDL tutorial and I ran the sample code as shown here:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "Failed to initialise SDL! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Failed to create window! SDL_Error: %s\n",     SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 255, 0, 0 ) );

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason no real border or title bar is being shown, it just displays a white screen. I tried using 
    SDL_SetWindowBordered but it did nothing. Next I set the background colour to red and from this image you can see there is a titlebar but there is no close or minimize button.[image: Window]
Does anyone know why this is happening. Is it just me or is it a problem with mac's?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `SDL_delay`? Add a simple event loop after initializing the window to prevent your app from closing immediately: `bool running = true;
 while(running)
 {
  SDL_Event e;
  while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
  {
   switch(e.type)
   {
    case SDL_QUIT:
     running = false;
     break;
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Yeah doing that worked, do you have an explanation to why this occurs?

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since getting rid of `SDL_Delay` seemed to help, I will try to elaborate a little. If we look at the code of `SDL_Delay` we can see that it basically does two things:

- if `nanosleep()` can be utilized, it does sleep for a time interval;
- else, it runs in an infinite `while` loop, checking how much time has passed @ each iteration, and `break`ing out of the loop after enough time has passed.

Now, I must say that I have never personally coded for osx, so I do not know how exactly does it draw it's windows. However I can assume that for some reason `SDL_Delay` in your code gets called (and effectively blocks the thread it's called from) *before* the OS manages to draw the header of the window, and after the delay finishes you immediately destroy the window yourself, thus the header is never properly drawn.

Comment: it's a weird problem but at least it's fixed

Answer (score 2):

I know that the answer is already solved, but for anyone who wants a  simple solution.

Example:

```
SDL_Delay(4000);
```

would turn into

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4000; i++){
    SDL_PumpEvents();
    SDL_Delay(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this has nothing to do with SDL_Delay() at all.

I tested it out, and it seems that on OSX the title-bar only updates each time the events are polled or pumped.

This means that SDL_Delay() blocks the title-bar rendering process if it prevents you from pumping events.

To fix this just call SDL_PumpEvents() every millisecond or so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < time_to_sleep; i++){
    SDL_PumpEvents();
    SDL_Delay(1);
}
```